# How to configure publishing server for clickonce

Tags: clickonce

I would like to deploy my app using ClickOnce. I choosen the 'publish' option from VS2010. I would like my users to install application from web site.

I am also having a bare server with only Win2008 installed on it. What else should I install on this server to enable clickonce? VS2010 wizard says, that I should enter URL of web site configured with FrontPage Server Extensions. What does it exactly mean? What should I do?

Thank you for help in advance

Answer (score 1):

I always feel it's easier to just publish for a specific deployment URL (or online only, then you can just publish) and then publish to the local filesystem, after which you just copy the published files to the webserver.

In that case, your webserver requirements are minimal: you need a webserver (doesn't even have to be IIS, you don't even need ASP.NET).

To actually publish directly to a webserver, you need IIS and frontpage server extensions => http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/134/installing-the-frontpage-server-extensions-on-iis

But I have actually never seen a case where that was usable, but maybe that's because we usually develop intranet apps.